# How to change notification time as stopwatch app on pause

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I Want to sync my Notification time with stop watch when app is **onPause** or **onStop**.

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setOngoing(StartRun)
    .setContentText( Lap + " " + s + " " ) 
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResour‌​ce(getResources(), R.drawable.a)) 
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.a); 

mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId,mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it your app's stopWatch or another app's ?

If the stopWatch belongs to your own app then simply run it on a Service and do your Notification business there.
although this won't work if your app's lifecycle is onDestroy.
however you wont need it to be running after your Activities onDestroy because mostlikely the stopWatch itself won't exist.

If the stopWatch belongs to another app or if it's your own app's but runs on backGround detached from your activities, then you need to make sure your Service's LifeCycle is not attached to the activity that started it as well.

And in case of stopWatch belonging to another app register a BroadCastListener to your service in the Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class MyService extends Service {
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("Timer",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences preferences1=getSharedPreferences("Lap",MODE_PRIVATE);
        seconds=preferences.getInt("time",0);
         hours=seconds/3600;
        String Lap=preferences1.getString("Lap","null");
         minutes=(seconds%3600)/60;
         sec=seconds%60;
        StartRun=true;
        final int mNotificationId = 001;
  /* Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app */
        Intent i = getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName())
                .setPackage(null)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED );

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);

        String s=("" + hours + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", sec));

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setOngoing(StartRun)
                        .setContentText( Lap + "  " + s + " " )
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.a);
                        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                    mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId,mBuilder.build());

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr;
}
```

Comment: This is my service class i've done my notification in it

Comment: But i want that when app is on pause service class is called and in it the notification should start counter from the time where app was stopped or paused and it should change digits like stopwatch in notification